# Adapting the path/string based on certain values

Tags: python

The user specifies the structure of the tree to save one or more files as a path (variable dir_depository). But the names of each sub-folders can change according to various parameters. (represented by dict_test here)

```
import configparser
import os
import re


dir_depository = r"C:\python\protocole\data\param_info"
dir_depository = dir_depository.split("\\")

dict_test = {'protocole' : 'POISSON',
            'data' : 'DATE',
            'param' : 'PRUNE',
            'info' : 'ILE FLOTANTE' }

liste=[]
def rename_path(dir_depository):
    for items in dir_depository:
        if items in dict_test:
            liste.append(dict_test[items])
        elif items == "_":
            liste.append(items)
        # () <- keep the separators
        # [] <- match everything in between
        # ^a-zA-Z0-9: <-except alphabets, upper/lower and numbers  and :  
        elif re.search('[^a-zA-Z0-9:]', items):
            items = re.split('([^a-zA-Z0-9])', items)
            function_a_nommer(items)
        else: 
            liste.append(items)
    return liste

liste = rename_path(dir_depository)

path = os.path.join(*liste)
```

My goal is to adapt the path values.

input: `C:\python\protocol\data\param_info`

desired ouput : `C:\python\POISSON\DATE\PRUNE_ILE FLOTANT`

But for now my output look like this : `C:python\POISSON\DATE\PRUNE\_\ILE FLOTANTE`

As you can see, I have some problem when it's like to special characters. I've focused on the "_" character for now but it would be nice if it could take into account other special characters.

The « \ » also doesn’t appear between « c : » and « python » and I don’t know why.

Comment: You could probably save yourself from unnecessary headache by using the `pathlib` module to manipulate paths: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html

Comment: using a module for paths is for sure the cleaner way to solve this. These also consider that the backslash in Windows is a forward slash in Linux/Mac, which might be an issue otherwise.

Comment: I was seeing the problem from the angle of replacing directlty the string. I will see what I can do with your indications.